# Bashrc profile was badly edited

Tags: bash

For error I have pasted:

```
export PATH=[...existing PATH additions]:/home/alumno/firefox/
```

on `~/.bashrc` and now I cant access to any command, even `sudo`, because terminal returns: command not found.
And when the terminal is opened gives a message:

```
bash: export: `additions]:/home/alumno/firefox/': not a valid identifier.
```

I need to edit bashrc somehow. Any help, please?

Comment: Whatever guide you are following is expecting you to fill in `[...existing PATH additions]` with your existing PATH contents.

Comment: Can you login as another user? Can you at least run this "/usr/bin/vi .bashrc" and edit the file?

Comment: I know but I made a mistake and pasted that line and then run source @KevinMGranger that's why I need help

Comment: @MatiasBarrios thanks, that was great.I was trying with another user but couldn't solve it. You can post as answer

Comment: @santimirandarp glad to hear!

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Great. As it was about configuring bashrc I wasn't sure. Thanks and I apologize @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the file with : `"/usr/bin/vi .bashrc"`

Regards!

Comment: 50 seconds to accept: Gracias! Aguante fernando cabrera :)

Comment: jajaja. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path for the commands.

Instead of `ls`, you need to call `/bin/ls` or in your case, use `/bin/vi ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I have tried with the solution of one comment just before the answer and as it worked I cant try it. But I assume is the same as @Matias Barrios. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to understand that when someone is typing an answer to a question, doesn't always realize that someone else has made a comment or answered to the same question. As the asker SO gives you full freedom to choose the answer you want.

Comment: Of course, I was just telling you why I accepted the other answer. Is it right?